# Run truncate in bigquery with Apache NiFi

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-nifi

I have a process that uses the **PutBigQueryBatch** processor, in which I would like it to truncate the table before inserting the data. I defined an **AVRO schema**, and previously created the table in BigQuery specifying how I wanted the fields. I am aware that if I change the **"Write Disposition"** property to the value **"WRITE_TRUNCATE"**, it will truncate the table. However, when I use this option, the schema of the table in BigQuery ends up being deleted, which I would not like to happen, and a new schema is created to record the data. I understand that the **"Create Disposition"** property exists, and that if the **"CREATE_NEVER"** option is selected, the schema should be respected and not deleted.

When I run this processor with the **"Write Disposition"** property set to **"WRITE_APPEND"**, the schema I created in BigQuery is respected, but with the **"WRITE_TRUNCATE"** not.

Is there any way to use the "WRITE_TRUNCATE" option and the table schema not be deleted?
Am I doing something wrong?
Below I forward the configuration that I am using in the PutBigQueryBatch processor:

[PutBigQueryBatch processor configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNM7M.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to run a `TRUNCATE TABLE` query before starting your process: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#truncate_table_statement

Comment: Yes, I would like to truncate table before writing new data, however native NiFi option is having this problem.